# HiveQL code to get the row count for each table in Hive

Tags: sql, hive

I'm trying to find a Hiveql query/code to count the rows on each table in a Schema in Hive.
I found this one,

```
SELECT
  '${hiveconf:hive.current.database}' AS database_name,
  t.tbl_name AS table_name,
  s.num_files,
  s.total_size
FROM
  tbls t 
CROSS JOIN 
  (
    SELECT  
      '${hiveconf:hive.current.database}' AS dbname,
      tblname,
      avg(numFiles) AS num_files, 
      avg(totalSize) AS total_size
    FROM schema_db_tbl
    GROUP BY tblname
  ) s
```

But seems like I cannot use hiveconfig.
Any alternatives?